# Sorting an array by occurrence of its elements efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this kind of array:

```
let mixedArr = ["Ship", "Ship", "Boat", "Ship", "Boat", "yacht" ]
```

I need a result that sorts the array by appearance, like this:

```
let sortedMixedArr = ["Ship", "Boat", "Yacht"]
```

Who can come up with a solution?

Comment: That's not sorting at all. Don't you just want `mixedArr.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index)`?

Comment: it has nothing to do with uniqueness, but with counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter approach by using the keys of the map and sort them by the count.

```js
var array = ["Ship", "Ship", "Boat", "Ship", "Boat", "Yacht"],
    map = array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map),
    result = [...map.keys()].sort((a, b) => map.get(b) - map.get(a));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for - a more efficient way than in previous posts. (hence "efficient" in the headline)

Comment: @falcon25 It is not "more efficien way" than my answer. It does basically the same. Actually `sort` that makes overall algo to have `O(n*log(n))` complexity. Additional mapping does not affect the complexity.

Comment: Thank you Yury also obviusly, and yes I meant shorter code not time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count items and then sort entries by count

```js
let mixedArr = ["Ship", "Ship", "Boat", "Ship", "Boat", "yacht" ]

console.log(
  sortByCount(mixedArr)
)

function sortByCount(arr) {
  return [...arr.reduce((map, item) => {
    if(map.has(item)) {
      map.set(item, map.get(item) + 1) 
    } else {
      map.set(item, 1)
    }
    
    return map
  }, new Map).entries()] // create [[name, count]]
  .sort(([_, a], [__, b]) => b - a) // sort by count numerically
  .map(([name]) => name) // extract names
}
```